# Retrieve passed data between pages with JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm generating some list items with JQuery Mobile. These list items have an id on the anchor. All anchors needs to load the page event.html. I need to retrieve the id when event.html is loaded.

On my index page I have the following code, which should pass the id from my anchor and refer me to event.html.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#overview a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.mobile.changePage('event.html', {
            transition: 'slide',
            data: {
                'id': 'this.id'
            }
        });
    });
});
```

On the page event.html I want to retrieve the data id.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#event', function() {
    //output data id
});
```

How do I do this?

I've seen some examples where people have tried to do this by using global variables and submitting through get request. I have not been able to successfully reproduce their solutions and I would prefer if the data could be passed directly from the pages. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

i think get method is the best , however I sometimes use the method data() , but you have to create a dummy element that is common among pages to keep you data ,  you can check this page though : 
http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Sounds good. How would you proceed with the get method in this example? I haven't been able to reproduce any of the examples I've found.

Comment: well with get method you have to combine your variables with the page you ar trying to open like this syntax  url:blabla.html?name1=xx&name2=yy , the browser , or web app , whatever will parse any string after the question mark exactly as if your defining variable , and you can use & to seperate among them , however in the page you are opening just don't forget to fetch these data using php script , never use this method to send encrypted though , like passwords or any valuable data , this might be useful :http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp